# Excel/VBA: Loop through cells in a row and assign the same function for each column

Tags: excel, vba

My vba knowledge is poor (started today) and I'm trying to build the following function. Web searches don't return what I want, probably because the search terms are too common.

I have something like this:

- A1 = name (Used as define name to build pull down list)
- A2 = list entry 1
- ...
- A10 = possibly up to list entry 9

Then in vba I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DropDownName As String
DropDownName = Trim(Range("A1").Value)
With Range("A11").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & DropDownName
End With
End Sub
```

This is then repeated for a whole bunch of columns, with the only change being the list name and contents. The idea is that if a user adds a new column with a new list, it will automatically place the pull down menu in Row 11 of that column.

The problem is that I don't know a simple way to apply that piece of code to all columns, row 11. I imagine it's easy, maybe a loop, but I just can't work out or find the solution! I've seen loop examples for a range of cells, but not for all cells in a row, or all populated cells in a row.

There are other improvements that can be made for this whole function I'm sure, e.g. to auto-generate the list from the cell contents instead of using the "Define name" menu option (one problem is that the list length can be different per column, and new items could be added/changed/removed, so it isn't just A2:A10). Feel free to suggest that too.

Thanks in advance.

!!!!UPDATE!!!!

Ok, following some further research, prompted by @Raystafarian's hint I changed it to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

...other code...

Dim DropDownName As String
Dim DropDownNameColumn As Long

DropDownNameColumn = ActiveCell.Column

If Target.Address <> Range(Cells(1, DropDownNameColumn), Cells(10, DropDownNameColumn)).Address Then
    DropDownName = Trim(Target.Range(Target.Column & "1").Value)

    With Target.Range(Cells(11, DropDownNameColumn)).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & DropDownName
    End With

End If
```

But, my spreadsheet doesn't update - if I change a cell in, eg, column B between rows 1&10, it should update column B11 with the validated list named the contents of B1.

Instead, nothing happens.

Comment: As a first hint - why are you using `Worksheet_Change`? You never reference `target` - does it need to run every time something changes?

Comment: This isn't the only process in the sub. Also, it doesn't need to run every time something changes, but that's a later optimisation.

Comment: If you are literally just starting out with VBA, I think that a better strategy is to spend a couple of weeks learning the core language and the basics of the Excel object model before you plunge into things like event handlers. Event handlers are typically short subs that dispatch to other subs which do the heavy lifting. First write the sub that does what you want it to do and then link it to an event handler which runs it automatically in certain situations.

Comment: `Formula1:="=" & DropDownName` only references row 1.  It should reference your list - e.g. `$A$2:$A$11`.  Are you trying to give the list a name (which would appear in the `Name Manager`) and then reference that name?

Comment: @John, that would be nice if I had the time, but I don't, I just need a solution so I'm having to short cut to a result using google, etc. Nevertheless, I'll see if I can do anything with your suggestions.
Darren, each list already has a name which I place in row 1 of each column, so that I can reference that name.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this, the main thing being that I wasn't indexing Range with the .Address value of the cell location.

```
If Target.Address <> Range(Cells(10, Target.Column), Cells(30, Target.Column)).Address Then
    DropDownName = Trim(Cells(10, Target.Column))

    With Range(Cells(31, Target.Column).Address).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & DropDownName
    End With
End If
```

Comment: This kind of digs a hole only to fill it up again. The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) can just as easily be written as `With Cells(31, Target.Column).Validation`. The [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) provide a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) reference just as valid as Range does.